# How to create gif images ID array in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gif, android-appwidget

How can i create an array of IDs of gif images i saved in the drawable file? If i create an int array for IDs it recognizes .jpg and .png only. I have already added the dependency and added mavenCentral() build.gradle and it implemented all that stuff successfully.

Comment: are you using a library to play the gif image?

Comment: a specific library in java?